# Issue with ordering JSON keys when marshalling an ordered map in Golang

Tags: json, dictionary, go

I have a requirement to iterate a given piece of JSON, and where an array contains a single item to convert that into a map. This is quite easy to do.

The catch is, I need to product a piece of JSON back to the client that is in the same order it was presented.

I have found some guides about using an OrderedMap, but that's inconsistent for me.

Sometimes I get the correct order, sometimes not.

https://go.dev/play/p/b9hmS9BEymy

Can anyone advise? From the logging it appear the issue may be with unmarshalling the incoming JSON

I am really reluctant to use structs, as the real JSON I need to process is very complex, and will need a huuuge amount of work as there are many variations.

Comment: You should come up with a minimal reproducabel example.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: In your playground attempt you start off by unmarshaling the input into a plain `map`, that's your mistake. Maps in Go **are by definition unordered**. Your `m` is out of order right from the start. You MUSTN'T unmarshal into a map if you want to retain the order of the incoming data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmarshalling json will not respect order, as you use `map[string]interface{}`. Map in golang is a hashmap, so no surprise there. What you should do is create an `UnmarshalJSON` function as well and do custom unmarshalling, otherwise there is no way to preserve order.

You can use standard unmarshalling for every other type, except map, which should make it a lot easier. If you want details on how to do that, I can explain that too

Comment: Yes I think this is the issue, the first unmarshal of the JSON.

I have found this example which allows use of OrderedMaps.

My concern however (with using maps at all) is that as noted in this library maps cannot be used concurrently - so I need to consider if using them in KrakenD API Gateway plugins would be safe

https://gitlab.com/c0b/go-ordered-json/-/tree/master/

Comment: if you really need to use ordered maps and you are concerned about concurrency, I would suggest using them and wrapping a rwmutex around. However, I struggle to come up with a legitimate use (one, which is not an anti-pattern) of a shared ordered map object, care to elaborate?

Comment: We are replacing a JSON service with a new JSON service. The new service gives a slightly different response to the old service, so we are using KrakenD response modifier plugin to tweak the new response to look like the old deprecated response.
We are obliged to make the response look *exactly* the same as we cannot be sure some clients haven't gone and written code to process the response based on index instead of key names..

Comment: Then why are you worrying about concurrency? Wouldn't each request be processed in single thread and not be shared? Then again, I know nothing about KrakenD

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever stumbles across this, I was able to solve it by using this package

https://gitlab.com/c0b/go-ordered-json

I had to Unmarshall the JSON into an orderedmap so the map contained the keys in the order they were presented, and then I was able to work through them from there:

```
var om *OrderedMap = NewOrderedMap()
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), om)
```